# Given a percentage of people who have a disease, what's the likelihood of catching it by meeting random people?

Tags: probability

As you might guess, this is more than a theoretical question at the moment.

I think that calculating this given that $x$% of people have the disease and someone interacts with $y$ people in a day, and if interacting with someone who has the disease, there's a $z$% change of transmission, then there's probably an equation that will tell me the likelihood of a person catching the disease on a given day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each person you meet, if the probability is $\frac{x}{100}$ that they have the disease and $\frac{z}{100}$ that they transmit it given that they have it, the probability is $\frac{xz}{10000}$ that they have the disease **and** will transmit it.

So you have a $1 - \frac{xz}{10000}$ chance of avoiding transmission from a single contact. This means a $(1 - \frac{xz}{10000})^y$ chance of avoiding transmission from $y$ contacts. The probability of catching the disease is the complement of this probability.